# UI - Image. Белая окантовка

Tags: unity3d

Добавил в игру прицел через добавление элемента - UI>Image. Настроил его, но в итоге появляется белая окантовка Image-окна. Как правильно ее отключить? Белые линии на скрине - это и есть окантовка(просто не уместилась в скрин вся..) Спасибо  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что из приведенного на скрине является белой окантовкой?

Comment: Белая окантовка это вот линии белые на скрине...

Comment: Это границы Canvas! Уберите отрисовку gizmos в режиме проигрывания. Рядом с statistics.

Comment: @Yaroslav спасибо. Все сработало

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если это появляется в игре, то наверно у вас включена кнопка Gizmos в окне Game сверху...
А если это появляется в редакторе, то так и должно быть.

Comment: Оформил мой комментарий в ответ?... wtf

Comment: @Yaroslav какой комментарий? EDIT: а, я этот комментарий только что увидел... Если хочешь, то я могу удалить свой ответ, а ты напишешь свой комментарий , но уже в виде ответа?